Selenium clicking on button webscrapping
I'm trying to use selenium to scrape data that requires you to push on each round to display more data, but I'm quite inexperienced with selenium and having trouble locating the element to scrape the data from
I'm using the selenium on google collab and locating by xpath, but it can't seem to find the element
options = Options()

options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = gs.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://dropstab.com/coins/centrifuge/fundraising')
button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/main/div/article/div/div/section/div/div[1]/section[1]/div/div[1]/button')
button.click()

For reference, the button is each of the fundraising rounds if you scroll down (Series A, Venture Round, etc)

but it can't seem to find the element Please show us the actual results of the code.  Vague guesses aren't really helpful.

@JohnGordon How do you show a misclicked element?

The code below will click on each of the Fundraising Rounds accordions and expand them. Before doing that, it closes the cookies banner.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

URL = "https://dropstab.com/coins/centrifuge/fundraising"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(2)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#cookiesAgreementDescription + button"))).click()
rounds = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Fundraising Rounds']//following-sibling::div/div")))
for _round in rounds:
    _round.click()


It says "Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (392, 558). Other element would receive the click: ...
(Session info: chrome-headless-shell=125.0.6422.76)"

It was working last week... not sure what changed. I updated the code... something about the site isn't working correctly so you have to pause for a couple seconds, then everything works fine.

You can get the fundraising info easier by parsing the Json data embedded in the page, e.g.:
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://dropstab.com/coins/centrifuge/fundraising"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__").text)

fundraising = data["props"]["pageProps"]["coin"]["fundraising"]

# print(json.dumps(fundraising, indent=4))

for s in fundraising["sales"]:
    print(s["name"], s["raised"])
    # ... print other info here
    print()

Prints:
Series A 15000000

Venture Round 4000000

Funding Round 3000000

Community Grants None

Early Ecosystem None

Rewards & Grants None

Core Contributors None

Total Backers None

Foundation Endowment None

Development Grants 1800000

Venture Round 4300000

Strategic Round 3700000

Seed 3800000

Main Sale Option 2 8882500

Main Sale Option 1 9350000

